# Rails Dup: remapping associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dup

I am cloning an active record model (called Projects) using "dup".  It has several associations; a project has many steps, steps have many images and videos, etc.

I'm finding that when I clone a project, it's successfully creating clones of the project's corresponding steps, images, and videos.  However, the images and videos still have the step_ids of the original steps, not the newly created one.  Is there an easy way for me to may the IDs to the newly created records?

I'm using the deep_cloneable gem.

This is how I'm creating my clone:

```
  # Create remix
  def remix
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @remix_project = @project.dup :include => [:steps, :images, :videos]
    @remix_project.remix = @project.id
    @remix_project.title = @project.title+" - "+current_user.username+" Remix"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @remix_project.save
        format.html { }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with nested attributes, you need to change the format as follows:

```
@remix_project = @project.dup :include => {:steps => [:images, :videos]}
```

Comment: it does not dup created_at values , how can that be duplicated ?